# How to map JSON response to custom class object

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer, unirest

I am calling an API in C# using [unirest.io](http://unirest.io/net.html). I get following JSON response (as *response.Body*).

```
{
    "persons": [{
        "id": "a010",
        "name": "Joe",
        "subjects": [
            "Math",
            "English"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "b020",
        "name": "Jill",
        "subjects": [
            "Science",
            "Arts"
        ]
    }]
}
```

I tried to map this to my custom class object as follows.

```
HttpRequest request = Unirest.get(API_V1_URL).header("accept", "application/json");
HttpResponse<string> response = request.asString();
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
persons = serializer.Deserialize<Persons>(response.Body);
```

But it always pass through by setting *persons.infos = NULL*;

**My Custom Class**

```
public class Persons
{
    public PersonInfo[] infos;
}

public class PersonInfo
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public string[] subjects;
}
```

Please assist me how can I correctly map such JSON to my .Net class objects ?

Comment: Here is a handy tool - simply paste in some example JSON, and it will generate a compatible C# object: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `Persons` in `Deserialize<T>` instead of `Vendors`

```
persons = serializer.Deserialize<Persons>(response.Body);
```

Rename property

```
public PersonInfo[] infos;
```

To

```
public PersonInfo[] persons;
```

Additionally, I would recommend you to use Auto-properties. i.e.

```
public PersonInfo[] persons{get;set;}
```

Comment: Passed Persons instead of Vendors (this was a typo).
Renamed infos to persons and that solved my problem. Thanks a lot.