# Getting the response body using Unirest with C#

Tags: c#, json, httprequest, unirest

About **Unirest for .Net**: https://github.com/mashape/unirest-net/

Here's my code excerpt:

```
Task<HttpResponse<MyClass>> response = Unirest.get("")
    .header("X-Mashape-Authorization", "")
    .asJsonAsync<MyClass>();

HttpRequest request = Unirest.get("");
```

**Question:** How do I get the response body?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, could you please clarify your question?

Comment: i useing "unirest.io .NET". and i want how to get response body

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How to map JSON response to custom class object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20907775/1497596).

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way:

```
HttpResponse<string> jsonResponse = Unirest.get("")
    .header("X-Mashape-Authorization", "")
    .asJsonAsync<string>();

var myBody = jsonResponse.Body;
```

As mentioned on the page of Unirest:

Upon recieving a response Unirest returns the result in the form of an Object, this object should always have the same keys for each language regarding to the response details.

.Code - HTTP Response Status Code (Example 200)
.Headers - HTTP Response Headers
.Body - Parsed response body where applicable, for example JSON responses are parsed to Objects / Associative Arrays.
.Raw - Un-parsed response body

Cheers, Martin